# Database Design for review system against trips like upwork using php mysql

Tags: php, mysql, database, database-design, relational-database

Hi I am designing a review based database design. I am having problem in this portion
how can I check if both users have given a review against each other on a social trip.just like we have a review system in upwork when job is complete both employer and freelancer can give reviews to each other same like i want to implement here if employer has not given review to freelancer then he will be shown give review on the screen against the job vice versa for Freelancer.
The same is here on my application difference is here in my app it is trip

I have a trip table,carry requests table,items and reviews tables

```
1- Trip table will have trips of users

2- Registered users can requests items on a trip 

3-When the registered user go to the other user created trip page then he can send the request to user against that trip to carry an item for him .
then an entry will be inserted in a carry_request table by sender_id which has requested the item and receiver id the user which has received the requests.
```

now I am having problem in designing the review table that 
how can i decide which user have given review to other user and which have not
also we will have 2 entries in a review table against each carry_request for review because against 1 carry request we will have 2 reviews one from sender and from receiver.

Here  is my query

```
select i.id as item_id,t.id as trip_id,us.id as sender_user_id,ur.fname as receiver_fname
from carry_requests cr
INNER JOIN users us on cr.sender_id = us.id
INNER JOIN users ur on cr.receiver_id = ur.id
INNER JOIN trips t on cr.trip_id = t.id
INNER JOIN items i on cr.item_id = i.id
where cr.sender_id = 24;
```

with this query I am getting all records against this user all was fine untill I have to found out which sender has not given review to receiver or which receiver has not given review to sender to show them a leave review button on the screen.
Here is my carry_requests table

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `carry_requests` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `sender_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `receiver_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `trip_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `item_id` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `is_sender_reviwed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `is_receiver_reviwed` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)

CREATE TABLE `trips` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `uid` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `from_location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `to_location` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
    `departDTTM` DATE NOT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `items` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `status` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `created_at` timestamp NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Review Table has

```
CREATE TABLE `reviews` (
    `id` INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    `trip_id` INT(11) NOT NULL,
    `reviewer_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', which has given the review 
    `user_id` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0', to whom review was given 
    `rating` INT(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
    `review` TEXT NULL,
    `created_at` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
```

Comment: you are looking for `LEFT JOIN`

Comment: @cmorrissey if their are two rows in reviews table then the left join will return me 2 records but i only want one record

Comment: @user5184398, what is reviewer_id and sender_id?

Comment: @ZeJur i have edited my post i have added a new table carry_request for simplicity but still having a problem in review please kindly check the edited answer for sender_id and reviwer_id please if you still have problem kindly ping i will update you on this and sorry for late reply

Comment: @user5184398, sorry for delay.
Now I see that You have two fields i.e. `is_sender_reviwed` & `is_receiver_reviwed` in  `carry_requests` table.

When sender or receiver posting his review on specific item you are inserting data to `review` table and thereafter You can update appropriate field in the `carry_requests` table.

and then You can get all the data with a little bit modified request:

`select i.id as item_id,t.id as trip_id,us.id as sender_user_id,ur.fname as receiver_fname,
cr.is_sender_reviwed, cr.is_receiver_reviwed' ...`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i am gonna answer this in terms of how Relationships between tables is setup in laravel:

First change **uid** to **user_id** in trips table SQL.

In the user model, do the following:

```
// User created reviews
public function created_reviews()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\Review::class, 'reviewer_id');
}

// Reviews on User
public function reviews()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\Review::class, 'user_id');
}

// Organized Trips
public function trips()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\Trip::class);   
}
```

In the trip model:

```
// Trip Organizer
public function organizer()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class);
}

// Trip Reviews
public function reviews()
{
  return $this->hasMany(App\Review::class);
}
```

In the reviews model:

```
// Review Creator
public function sender()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class,'reviewer_id');
}

// Review Receiver
public function receiver()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(App\User::class,'user_id');
}

// Associated Trip
public function trip()
{
  return $this->belongsTo(App\Trip::class);
}
```

If you run the following code:

```
$user = User::find(10)->with(['reviews','created_reviews','trips','trips.reviews']);
```

It will give you the following:

- Reviews done on user.
- Reviews created by user.
- Trips organized by user.
- Reviews done on the trips organized by user.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

can you describe the structure of relations between a trip & review as well as reviewer & sender?

Here is what i am assuming:

1. A trip can have multiple reviews.
2. A trip can have only one organizer.
3. A user can leave a single review for organizer

Am i correct in this?

Comment: i have editted my question please kindly check the question for this 
i have updated my design by adding a carry_request table for this but still having problem in the review

Comment: on 1 trip a user can send request a item to carry for him to the trip owner then an entry will be made in carry_request table.
against that carry_request both users will give review to each other mean we will have two reviews on from sender who send the request send_id and receiver_id who  receives the requests